# Ubuntu Server 18.04.1: mount raid 1 as /boot partition

Tags: boot, server, mount, raid

I have 6 disks (2x 1tb and 4x 4tb) and want the following setup:

- 2x 1tb disks in raid 1 (mounting point /)
- 4x 4tb disks in raid 5 (mounting point /home)

I got the following messages:

> If you put all disks into RAIDs or LVM VGs, there will be nowhere to put the boot partition.

and

> You must mount a partition of a local disk at /boot to continue.

[help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) says:

> Warning: the /boot filesystem cannot use any softRAID level other than 1 with the stock Ubuntu bootloader. If you want to use some other RAID level for most things, you'll need to create separate partitions and make a RAID1 device for /boot.

I also tried to split the raid 1 in two raid 1, one to mount as / and one to mount as /boot, but i am not able to select /boot as mounting point for the second array (greyed out).

What did i forgot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched to the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS **alternate** server image. Here it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use an usb stick for /boot ext4  bypassing your problem
Any of the drive fails you will still boot from the usb stick and will work the degraded drive.

Comment: This is a smart solution. I always have a non-raid drive boot drive for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in the new installer: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1785332

Downloading the alternative installer seems to fix it:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer

Make sure the *.iso file name does *not* contain "live" in the file name if you want to use the alternative server image.