# Ubuntu Server 20.04 RAID1 + LVM encrypted partition: problem with GRUB

Tags: server, partitioning, 20.04, encryption, raid

On the new **Ubuntu Server 20.04 I was unable to create an encrypted partition with "RAID + LVM"**. The installation process finished correctly, but at the startup GRUB wasn't found, and I was redirected in the **"GRUB minimal bash"**.

Here I will describe how I proceeded during the installation.
First, I have prepared both the hard drives (SSD in my case) using **"GParted Live"** (I created a bootable USB with the GParted ISO):

1. 512 MB partition, named "/bios/efi", fat32, flagged as "boot, esp";
2. 10 GB / partition, named "/", ext4, flagged as "raid";
3. /home partition, named "/home", ext4, flagged as "raid";

Then, using the **"Custom storage layout"** during the Ubuntu Server 20.04 installation:

1. I checked **both disks to be "added as a boot disk"**
2. and then using the **"Create software RAID (md)"** I have created a new "md0" volume (always active)
3. and then I created another **"RAID md"** volume (always active)
4. At this time I selected the **"Create Volume LVM"** and I choose the **"md0"** partition and I assigned a passphrase to it.
5. I selected again the **"Create Volume LVM"** and I choose the **"md1"** partition and I assigned a passphrase.
6. Now I selected the **"vg0"** partition and choose "Add GPT Partition", and than I selected "Create logical volume" and mount on "/"
7. Similar things for the **"vg1"** partition where I choose "Add GPT Partition", and than I selected "Create logical volume" and mount on "/home"
8. After that I choose **"done"** and I completed the installation
9. After the reboot the OS entered in the **"GRUB minimal bash"**

What's is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @jdurston for your reply, **I was able to install Ubuntu 20.04 with RAID 1 and encrypted disks in this way**.

I have prepared both the hard drives using **"GParted Live"** (I created a bootable USB with the GParted ISO):

**Disk 1:**

1. 512 MB partition, named **"/bios/efi", fat32, flagged as "bios_grub"**;
2. 10 GB / partition, named "/", ext4, flagged as "raid";
3. (Entire remaining space) /home partition, named "/home", ext4, flagged as "raid";

**Disk 2:**

1. 512 MB partition, named **"/bios", fat32, flagged as "boot, esp" (*ATTENTION*: it's flagged differently compared to disk 1)**;
2. 10 GB / partition, named "/", ext4, flagged as "raid";
3. (Entire remaining space) /home partition, named "/home", ext4, flagged as "raid";

Then, using the **"Custom storage layout"** during the Ubuntu Server 20.04 installation:

1. **I choose only the disk one** to be "added as a boot disk";
2. and then using the **"Create software RAID (md)"** I have created a new "md0" volume (always active) selecting both 10 GB partition;
3. and then I created another **"RAID md"** volume (always active) selecting both remaining 222 GB partition;
4. then I selected the **"Create Volume LVM"** and I choose the 512 MB partition (previously called /boot) and **I leaved it not encrypted**;
5. I selected again the **"Create Volume LVM"** and I choose the **"md0"** partition and I assigned it a passphrase;
6. then I selected again the **"Create Volume LVM"** and I choose the **"md1"** partition and I assigned it a passphrase;
7. I selected the **"vg0"** partition and choose "Add GPT Partition", and than I selected "Create logical volume" and mount on **"/boot"**;
8. then I selected the **"vg1"** partition and choose "Add GPT Partition", and than I selected "Create logical volume" and mount on **"/"**;
9. Same things for the **"vg2"** partition where I choose "Add GPT Partition", and I selected "Create logical volume" and mount on **"/home"**;
10. After that I choose **"done"** and I completed the installation;
11. **After the reboot GRUB worked correctly!**

I am attaching two images from "Storage Configuration" of Ubuntu 20.04 installation, in the first image you will see the situation before the RAID creation (after the GParted mods), and a second image where you will see the final situation before hitting "done".

**Image 1, before the RAID creation:**

[image]

**Image 2, after RAID creation:**

[image]

Comment: What about hardware RAID1 (eg with hp p410i)? Will the approach be the same or should altered?

Comment: @Oleksa I think that the approach is a bit different because you need to configure your "HP P410" board, but I never used it before. I know that on Ubuntu Server there's the "HP Array Configuration Utility" (HP ACU). The utility allows you to view and configure the drives connected to the RAID controller.

Comment: @Oleksa the driver seems to be this one: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man4/hpsa.4.html (this is the man page)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar problem. After no luck with various permutations in a VM I stumbled across [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/hhvucx/full_disk_encryption_install_with_efi/), where user wRAR_ says '[Debian installer] currently doesn't support encrypted /boot'. Ubuntu is based on Debian; I don't know to what extent the installers are similar, but I tested both in a VM, with and without encrypted `/boot`. Both failed to boot, presenting the GRUB shell you describe in your question.

NOTE: Designating an encrypted area as the mount point for `/`, and not designating a separate `/boot` mount point, means that `/boot` will reside under that encrypted `/`.

Broadly this means, if we want some kind of encrypted LVM ontop of RAID, there are two options:

**Option 1** - what I chose to do, and is more beginner-friendly since it can be accomplished with the standard Ubuntu installer.

**Encrypt everything except /boot and /boot/efi**

All user data will be encrypted, but the entire contents of `/boot` (not just `/boot/efi`) will not.
The partition scheme you describe is different, but **the key thing is that - for this to work - `/boot` should not reside on an encrypted partition**.

I used the following partition scheme:

[My encrypted LVM on RAID1 partition scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAds2.png)

I was able to accomplish it all in the installer:

sda1: 512M /boot/efi

sdb1: 512M /boot

sda2 & sdb2: RAID1 array md0

md0: Encrypted volume dm_crypt-0

dm-_crypt-0: logical volume vg0-lv--0 for /

dm-_crypt-0: logical volume vg0-lv--1 for /srv

Of course you can choose whatever logical volumes you like inside the volume group: I have a separate /srv for a server setup.

One small advantage of this setup is it makes use of both the 512M unencrypted spaces - unlike the typical scheme of encrypted LVM on RAID1 - with just the efi partition unencrypted. It's not ideal, but I tested it and it worked for me.*

**Option 2**:
There may be a way to circumvent the installer not supporting encrypted `/boot` by dropping-out to a shell, editing some configuration files and reinstalling GRUB among other things. [This blog post](http://www.chinnodog.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-fde-boot/) seems to have some instructions but I haven't followed them.

*(Although I must say I found the installer's partitioning menu a little awkward in places - it seems to automatically grab certain unformatted space assuming it can use it as the EFI partition; but with a little 'gaming' of the options I got there in the end)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jdurston, it was very useful, I replied to my question with the procedure that I used. Hope that it will be useful for other Ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different approach.

It is true that you cannot configure at first grub to activate and boot from a encrypted partition (although you could insmod and configure grub to do so...). Therefore, I suggest the following configuration scheme:

md0: LVM with LUKS (at VG level, I could not find how to do it at LV level using the installer) /, /var, ...

md1: /boot (just boot straight into the partition)

By doing this, you have a different partition/RAID configuration for /boot and the encrypted partitions. Do not forget to grub-install on sdb afterwards in case your sda fails.