# Server installation on SoftwareRAID fails with subiquity error

Tags: server, system-installation, 20.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my new private custom server. This is the hardware:

- Motherboard Asus P11C-I with Intel Software RAID controller
- 1x Intel Xeon E-2136 6x 3.30GHz So. 1151 BOX
- 2x 16 GB Corsair DDR4-2666 RAM
- 2x 250 GB m.2 SSD on a DeLock PCI-Express Card > 2 x internal M.2 NGFF attached to the SATA ports

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNcnM.jpg) error after partitioning/being asked for user data. Even when installing Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS I get the error.

During installation, I updated the installer, created a network bonding device and partitioned the SSD's with software raid 1 devices md0 (/boot) and md1 (/root) following [this ubuntu guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices)

no errors during booting the machine, 32 GB RAM are detected, both sumsung SSD's and CPU also.

This ist not my first ubuntu server to install, but first one with software RAID. I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After disabling the RAID feature and enabling AHCI mode in BIOS, installation worked. But I am curious why I need that Software RAID controller at all then ?