# Install Ubuntu 20.04 DESKTOP with Software RAID 1 on two disks

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, raid, live-cd

So I have looked far and wide (but maybe not enough) for the answer.  Historically, you could avoid the LiveCD and use the alternateCD / text installer to configure software RAID 1 on two internal disks at the start of install. Apparently this is [still working for Ubuntu 20.04 SERVER edition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices?newreg=4fc24a7a37ed49f99202ecc00bbfc1d0).  But I cannot find a solution for the DESKTOP edition as it only seems to come via a LiveCD now.  I need displays and TK as the application I am testing in different environments needs that.  Am I missing something obvious?  Is there a slew of packages I could install to turn a server edition into the desktop?

The computer system has two independent disks and no hardware raid -- either in a controller or in the BIOS. So it has to be setup in software.  While I can configure each disk with the partitions expected, I cannot tie them together into a logical RAID volume to present to the Live CD installer.  I could do this in earlier editions using the AlternateCD installer.  Best I can tell anything but the Live Installer has been deprecated with no intent to support the Alternate in the Desktop release. Ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not restricted to using only Ubuntu Server packages just because you installed Ubuntu Server initially.

1. Install Ubuntu server and configure RAID
2. Install the desktop GUI components

```
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt install tasksel
   $ sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop  
   $ reboot
```

If GUI does not start after the reboot:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
$ reboot
```

Credit: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-gui-installation