# Read RAID array from partitions within ISO files and disks

Tags: raid, mdadm

How can I assemble a RAID5 array using `mdadm`, if my disks are actually partitions, and some of them are image files, rather than actual disks? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

I have an old RAID 5 array that I want to recover. It once consisted of three 2 TB disks, each with a single 2TB partition on it. I have two of them as image files (created with `dd`), and one as the actual HDD. I was hoping to access the RAID5 array's contents, but I'm not able to even reassemble the array, let alone mount it. Here's what I tried:

**Create loop devices for the image files**

```sh
losetup -Pf image1.iso
losetup -Pf image2.iso
```

**Create a custom `~/raid-mdadm.conf`**

```
DEVICE /dev/sdc1
DEVICE /dev/loop17p1
DEVICE /dev/loop33p1
```

**Try to run `mdadm --assemble`**

```sh
mdamd --assemble --scan --verbose --config=~raid-mdadm.conf
```

however, this fails with the following error:

```
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: Merging with already-assembled /dev/md/0
mdadm: cannot re-read metadata from /dev/dm-8 - aborting
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I don't specify my custom `--config` option, or if I use `--config=partitions`, the output shows that it doesn't actually consider `/dev/sdc1`, `/dev/loop17p1`, or `/dev/loop33p1` in the `--scan` phase.

PS: If you're wondering why there's these partitions involved, don't ask me. I don't remember why I decided that over 10y ago. If you're wondering why I don't either have all disks, or all images, this is because my computer doesn't seem to want to recognize more than one disk at at time, and I don't have enough free storage for a 3rd image *and* the data I want to recover.

PS2: I'd also be happy to reassemble my RAID array using something other than `mdadm`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `man mdadm` command and check the integrity of the array, use `mdadm --zero-superblock --force` to clean up superblocks from failed attempts that may already contain service information.

For a 6-disk RAID-5 with 1TB disk, the failure rate due to BER is estimated at 4-5%, and 4-disk for 4TB disk, it will already reach 16-20%.
And if you use BER (Bit Error Rate), further increases the probability of failure during a massive read of the entire disk volume. RAID-5 this was the first and final error.
I can already see it here: `/dev/md/0` vs `/dev/md0`.
Check your `raid-mdadm.conf ' file.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what this means: "RAID-5 this was the first and final error". If you're saying I shouldn't have picked RAID5 to begin with, then I'm afraid I can't do much about that past decision now.

Comment: Okay, but given the possible RAID-5 failures and looking at the output `/dev/md/0`... After all, it is not clear, it is assembled in this way or it is only an error in the configuration file. It block `/0` now.

Comment: I have provided the full config file that I have. It contains only those 3 lines. The reason I created that `~/raid-mdadm.conf` file was to instruct `mdadm` to use the correct partitions, because without it, it would not look at those.

Comment: Check out this post, maybe it will help you.... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299978/install-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios  The path to the /etc/_.conf file is specified there. Target databases that you are trying to create.... and much more.