# Add RAID 1 pair to running system 21.04 with UEFI boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, raid, 21.04

I find many answers to this question for Ubuntu 12 and 14, but with EFI partitions things have changed a bit. Actually using those guides I do have an older system running RAID1 but I have run into trouble, well speed bumps.

The older RAID system had my backup and nextcloud data, which I have moved to the new system, recreated raid and copied.

This is what I have running right now:

```
Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624  959449087  958398464  457G Linux RAID
/dev/sda3  959449088 7814035455 6854586368  3.2T Linux RAID


Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1050624  959449087  958398464  457G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3  959449088 7814035455 6854586368  3.2T Linux RAID

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdc2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux filesystem
```

The system currently boots from /dev/sdc

I have tried a few things with a Live CD to copy sdc1 and sdc2 to sda and sdb and make them bootable.

I found this post quiet interesting
[Install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299978/install-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios/)

I think it has many of the details I have been missing.

Specifically step 4.1 chroot to the raid file system
I have mdadm installed and configured so all that is left is

```
Update the module list the kernel should load at boot.

echo raid1 >> /etc/modules
Update the boot ramdisk

update-initramfs -u
Finally, exit from chroot
```

and then continue with steps 5 onward.

I honestly think the key point I was missing was adding raid1 to /etc/modules
In the older docs (Ubuntu 12 etc) I think it was handled in the grub files