# Install Ubuntu 22.04 Server with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS?

Tags: boot, uefi, raid, lvm, luks

I followed the instructions here - [Install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299978/install-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios) but used the Ubuntu Server Installer to configure the partition layout and added an extra step of creating encrypted partition managed by LVM,

After the installation and a reboot it just drops me to a grub prompt.

The install ends up with the layout below, before choosing reboot:

```
    NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
...
|-sda1                8:1    0     1G  0 part  /target/boot/efi
`-sda2                8:2    0  23.9G  0 part  
  `-md0               9:0    0  23.9G  0 raid1 
    `-md0p1         259:1    0  23.9G  0 part  
      `-dm_crypt-0  253:0    0  23.9G  0 crypt 
        `-vg0-lv--0 253:1    0  23.9G  0 lvm   /target
sdb                   8:16   0    50G  0 disk  
`-md1                 9:1    0    50G  0 raid1 
  `-dm_crypt-1      253:2    0    50G  0 crypt 
sdc                   8:32   0    50G  0 disk  
`-md1                 9:1    0    50G  0 raid1 
  `-dm_crypt-1      253:2    0    50G  0 crypt 
sdd                   8:48   0    25G  0 disk  
|-sdd1                8:49   0     1G  0 part  
`-sdd2                8:50   0  23.9G  0 part  
  `-md0               9:0    0  23.9G  0 raid1 
    `-md0p1         259:1    0  23.9G  0 part  
      `-dm_crypt-0  253:0    0  23.9G  0 crypt 
        `-vg0-lv--0 253:1    0  23.9G  0 lvm   /target
...
```

I then entered a chroot into /target and installed mdadm, cryptsetup as well as lvm2 and ran `update-initramfs -u -k all`,

Checking the status of md0 I see that it is running and intact.

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Dec 15 23:53:14 2023
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 25094144 (23.93 GiB 25.70 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 25094144 (23.93 GiB 25.70 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Dec 18 19:46:37 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : ubuntu-server:0
              UUID : b233dc76:68e9667a:90caf67d:248a5d57
            Events : 457

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       50        0      active sync   /dev/sdd2
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
```

The output of blkid with the parts pretaining to the boot disks,

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="6E2B-4461" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a78ee060-80ff-48b5-8f28-968ba4a058d8"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b233dc76-68e9-667a-90ca-f67d248a5d57" UUID_SUB="0c2ddd98-fd1f-4dc7-9101-13966ce90210" LABEL="ubuntu-server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="26ffcb1e-e49c-4920-9d4d-c6699422a25e"

/dev/sdd1: UUID="6E53-B051" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="566d3ac6-5c0b-4235-979d-2034e7a9b31e"
/dev/sdd2: UUID="b233dc76-68e9-667a-90ca-f67d248a5d57" UUID_SUB="e5a0cf7c-306e-9ca1-4669-5c72558ae229" LABEL="ubuntu-server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="5fc3721e-2f79-43b7-bb41-d1aad99acd53"

/dev/md0p1: UUID="58f96d67-465c-400f-bb07-145330231c9f" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="daedffe6-6c65-45b9-a0d0-dd48559c49d2"

/dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0: UUID="TJqD5z-843X-5r0D-QSzv-9mZG-Z3Ns-LtkdTb" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv--0: UUID="2a0a9c3d-c9b7-4bf3-94df-cf59ea51bcac" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

The the contents of `/etc/crypttab`

```
dm_crypt-0 UUID=58f96d67-465c-400f-bb07-145330231c9f none luks
dm_crypt-1 UUID=0d2970ec-903a-4692-87d7-f23557837e0e none luks
```

and the contents of `/etc/fstab`

````
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/vg0/lv-0 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-N1205C9Cu7efVNdldEmtXnybJIAatiWaasaZc5e7x8qbTMn3MpiPZwSgvIY9TjT5 / ext4 defaults 0 1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6E2B-4461 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0```
````

Everything appears to be correctly configured as far as I can tell but I still end up on the grub prompt after a second reboot....

What hasn't been configured correctly, or did I encounter a bug?