# Ubuntu 20.04 server installer crashes when setting up raid 1 drives for /boot (md0) and / (md1). Has anyone been successful?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, raid

I’ve setup two drives (sda And sdb — both are MBR disks ) with same partition tables. Within Ubuntu server 20.04 server installer I set up Md0 and md1 as RAID 1 for /boot and / mountpoints respectively and set sda as boot device. I’m able to go to next screen to enter my profile (username , computer name, etc). While at that screen the installer crashes and offers to restart. I’ve already sent the report to canonical, but was wondering if anyone has a workaround? Has anyone any success with using this installer for RAID 1?

Comment: This post answered my question.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices