# Grub Rescue Problem (Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS & No Windows)

Tags: grubrescue

I first created a bootable USB stick on Windows as explained on https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview. I then installed Ubuntu on my PC following the instructions described on the link https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview. When the installation is completed, and after restarting the PC, I got the following error message:

> error: no such partition.
> Entering rescue mode...
> grub rescue>

[image: Photo of error message]

In order to repair the grub, I booted into Ubuntu on the USB and followed the steps on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Then, I also tried to change the boot order in BIOS to 1 Internal HDD, 2 Secondary HDD, ..., but I am still having the same issue.

The report of my boot-repair process is on https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RXWwGqGNsP/. Could you help me solve this problem?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Is this a RAID system as it seems to show that. If using RAID are you installing the server version? And what version of Ubuntu? Normally for servers the most current LTS or 20.04 is recommended. Desktop does not have the RAID drivers. And better to use software RAID rather than hardware RAID in most cases.

Comment: This is a RAID system, yes. I had Windows 7, was not able to update the system. My VGA chip got broken. Windows 7 got totally broken down too. After repair, Windows 10 was installed. It was really really slow. I deleted Windows, and am now trying to install and use Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. I have installed the desktop version.

Comment: VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92GLM [Quadro FX 3800M] (rev a2), width: 64 bits, clock: 33MHz

Comment: The PC is a Dell Precision M6500.

Comment: I do not really know the differences between the desktop and the server versions. Please do let me know more about them.

Comment: @oldfred.......

Comment: This is a x86_64 machine.

Comment: It has an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU, X 940 @ 2.13GHz.

Comment: There is a similar problem on the following link too: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1703431.

Comment: If RAID 0, not recommended, as you have to have data backed up elsewhere, probably daily, as if either drive breaks all data is lost. I have seen users break RAID and just use system as two drives, but that also erases everything. Or download server version and then install desktop of your choice. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#1-overview

Comment: It is supposed to be RAID 0, but "lshw" or "lshw | grep raid -i" does not produce anything related to the RAID controller. Does this mean it is broken? @oldfred

Comment: Do not know RAID, but you need RAID drivers that are part of server, not normally installed in desktop. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices Ubuntu Software RAID vs FakeRaid vs Hardware RAID. Home user
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422516&p=13873154#post13873154  & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444499

Comment: There was a fake raid on my PC. I removed the data related to that raid setting on the terminal with dmraid ... and dd... commands, and reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. Now it is working well.