# Install Ubuntu 20.04.3 in RAID0 on two SSDs

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, ssd, raid

I’m trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 on 2 X Samsung Pro 980 2TB in RAID0. I have YouTubed and googled a lot but simply can’t make it work.

Option A: When I create the partitions: /, SWAP and BOOT on both disks the interface will not let me create a RAID array on the disks?

[image]
[image]

Option B: If I try to create the RAID0 first, and the partitions then I’m not allowed to set the BOOT disk?

[image]

‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: Never used RAID. RAID with 20.04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices But RAID 0 is normally not recommended.  Its only used for systems where all data is stored elsewhere all the time. Don't bother with RAID 0 unless you have a specific need for speed without data redundancy, since if one drive goes out, you lose the whole array.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444499 & http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/nas/nas-features/31745-data-recovery-tales-raid-is-not-backup

Comment: 1. That doesn't answer my question. 2. Yes I do have a specific need for using RAID0. 3. It doesn't matter what RAID I'm selecting this issue is the same.