# How to use dd to clone single drive to raid1?

Tags: grub2, raid, dd, clone, clonezilla

Running `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/md126` is taking some time so it seems like it's working but I am not sure what else may need to be done after to make the system bootable.

When trying to mount `/dev/md126` it says: `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md126, missing codepage or elper program, or other error.`

`/dev/sda` is the source drive (256GB SSD)

`/dev/md126` is the target drive (512GB SSD RAID 1) - setup using bios/motherboard RAID controller. So fake RAID I believe.

Tried using Clonezilla but it didn't detect the `/dev/md126` device, just the individual drives (`sdb/sdc`).

Do I need to edit `/etc/fstab` on target disk and set up grub after? What commands are necessary?

Comment: I do not think that works. Your dd will just totally erase the first 250GB of the target making it an identical image of your sda. It also copies all empty space, so dd is always slow. If an install better to reinstall so configuration is correct for RAID, and rsync all data from your normal backup into new install. Also most post that fake RAID is not preffered. Ubuntu Software RAID vs FakeRaid vs Hardware RAID. Home user
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422516&p=13873154#post13873154

Comment: Looking into a hardware RAID1... any recommendations for something inexpensive but reliable? Just needs two ports.

I'm definitely avoiding doing a reinstall if I can.

Comment: I do not know RAID nor servers. But what I have seen is that RAID is for uptime, not backup. So why RAID? Link has info on Software RAID which I often see recommended. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices & http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/nas/nas-features/31745-data-recovery-tales-raid-is-not-backup

Comment: In short, a RAID 1 config is just better than a single drive, at least there's one backup. Then the whole thing can actually be backed up to an external. But yes also uptime in case one dies, it's fine for a while.