# RAID validation fails during Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, raid, 22.04, mdadm

I've followed [Install Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa with RAID 1 on two devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices) to set up RAID 1 during the installation of Ubuntu Server 22.04, yet installation always fails with a RAID validation error (I also tried with Ubuntu 20.04). Debian can configure RAID successfully and complete the setup.

Disk layout:

[image: disk layout]

RAID setup:

[image: raid setup]

Validation error:

[image: validation error]

Comment: Would be nice to find a solution to this.  It makes our PXE installer for Ubuntu 22.04 completely unusable, as it is nice to have RAID1 for redundancy on boot disks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Do you see the line where it says:

comparing device lists: expected ['/dev/sdb2', '/dev/sdb2'] found: ['/dev/sdb2', 'dev/sda2']

That's a huge WTF right there, as it's apparently looking for sdb2 twice rather than sdb2 and sda2.  This is definitely a problem with the installer.

I found a simple and effective workaround.  What you do is you just create the raid array as --level=1 -n 2  so you essence have a mirror with no mirror.  Then you build your lvm vg on top of that, and the installer is fine with it.  When you're done, and the system boots, you add the second partition (on the other disk) to the md and now you're fine.

It's a problem with the installer, I couldn't find any other workaround.  It's still present in 22.04.2 by the way.

Comment: Could you supply some references please.